# codeigniter query question

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

There is probably a simple solution to this question, but if i have the function below and $events contains an unknown number of integers, how would I use the $events variable in a query like this?

```
function remove_events($events)
{
    $sql = "delete from events where event_id in $events";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I should have clarified. $events is an array with an unknown number of integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if $event is a single value then you must use

```
$sql = "delete from events where event_id = $events";
```

Or if it is an array

```
$sql = "delete from events where event_id in (".implode(',', $events).") ";
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Would I need to escape my $events array too?

Answer (score 1):

the following sql syntax should help you to resolve your queries .

delete FROM events WHERE event_id IN ('2','3');

In the above example (2,3) should be a codeigniter array.

Answer (score 0):

hope that you have the contents in $events as like 1,2,3... . if so no problem, else if you have spaces between the numbers , use like this format.
`implode(',',explode(' ',$events));`
give it a try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Let Active Record make the job:

```
$this->db->where_in('id', $events)->delete('events');
```

All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.

Comment: Sorry! Where it says 'where' should say 'where_in'. Editing right now!